# Replace IE conditional statements for IE 10+

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser, conditional-comments

IE 10+ does not support conditional statements. This makes developing for IE 7-11 tricky becaues IE10-11 parses the content within a conditional statement rather than ignoring it. For example:

```
<!--[if (IE 9) | (IE 8)]><!-->
   // Code here will get rendered by IE10 & IE11
<!--<![endif]-->
```

So, if I want to have some code that will get rendered in IE 8 & 9 only, and then some code that will get rendered in IE10, IE11 & Firefox only, how do I do it?

EDIT: Note that I am not talking about styles here; I want to support significant structural changes in my webpage. E.g.:

```
<!--[if (IE 9) | (IE 8)]><!-->
   <div>
      <div>
         Test
      </div>
   </div>
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if (IE 10]><!-->
   <div>
      <h3>Test</h3>
   </div>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. If you want some code to be executed by IE10+ and other browsers, isn't what you have the answer?

Comment: No, because I want one block of code to be executed in IE8+9 only and for that block to be ignored by IE10+11. And another for IE10+11 only, ignored by IE8+9.

Comment: Conditional comments are now obsolete : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But why do you want some code to have some specific for IE10 / IE11 (and not make the same thing as on FF / Chrome /...)?

Comment: It seems like your only option is browser sniffing, which I don't recommend by any means.

Comment: No, OP meant the new IEs rendered the **"fallback CSS"**, which was meant for the old IEs.

Comment: If you're not talking about styles, the [css] tag is inappropriate and confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work on my end. It looks like the format for the conditional statement was off.

```
<!--[if (IE 9) | (IE 8)]>
  Code here will not get rendered by IE10 & IE11
<![endif]-->
```

Also, what type of code are you rendering, js, css?

Comment: I want IE10&11 to NOT display code wrapped in that conditional.

Comment: @JohnSmith please read his answer again **clearly**. you did something wrong

Comment: @John Smith: FYI, the answer has since been edited. Looks like we all got a bit confused there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only IE8/9 to render a different set of markup from *everything else* (meaning IE10+ receives the same code as all other browsers), that's entirely doable:

- You need to hide the `(IE 9) | (IE 8)` condition from all other browsers. This means having the comment portion encapsulate the entire block of code, not just the conditional expressions.
- You need to allow all other browsers to see the other condition, while preventing IE8/9 from seeing that portion.

  The `(IE 10)` portion is fine; IE8 and IE9 will know that they don't satisfy the condition and so will not render the markup even though it isn't commented out, whereas IE10 will never see the condition regardless (and neither will any later versions), so it will render the markup as it's not being hidden in a comment.

Hence:

```
<!--[if (IE 9) | (IE 8)]>
   <div>
      <div>
         Test
      </div>
   </div>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if (IE 10)]><!-->
   <div>
      <h3>Test</h3>
   </div>
<!--<![endif]-->
```